# Test complaining about not finding a component, but it there

Tags: reactjs

I get this error even though I think my exports are correct...

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

      87 |   test('creates a reminder when submiting the form if all fields are filled', async () => {
      88 |     const history = createMemoryHistory()
    > 89 |     const { findByText, getAllByTestId, getByTestId } = render(
         |                                                         ^
      90 |       <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      91 |         <Reminders />
      92 |       </BrowserRouter>
```

this is my test:

```
import Reminders from '../Reminders/Reminders'
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent, wait, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'


  test('creates a reminder when submiting the form if all fields are filled', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    const { findByText, getAllByTestId, getByTestId } = render(
      <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <Reminders />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )

    const categoriesMenu = await findByText('categories-menu')
    expect(categoriesMenu).toBeTruthy()

  })
```

And this is my Reminders component:

```
function Reminders() {
  return (
    <ReminderProvider>
      <div className="pa2 mw6 center">
        <Route path="/" exact component={AddReminder} />
        <Route path="/overview" component={ReminderOverview} />
        <Route path="/reminder/:id" component={Reminder} />
      </div>
    </ReminderProvider>
  )
}

export default Reminders
```

Any ideas whats the issue, to me the imports are fine..
Thanks.

Comment: What react router version you are using?

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what's a `ReminderProvider`, for example?